# Handling HTTP errors in PHP file upload

Tags: php

```
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);
```

If I have the above and upon validation if the error is true what does the error mean?

Comment: Using the `@` symbol suppresses error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors codes are listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php